# facing issue in String replace with spl characters while writing to excel java

Tags: java, excel

I am using java with an input String `" "!@#$^%^&*()(*{}|:"<>?" "`.

while writing to excel .. the value is changing to  `!@#$^%^&*()(*{}|:"<>?""`

I tried replaceAll and replace method.. didnt help.
Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use escape character like this:

```
String qualdata    = "\"\"!@#$^%^&*()\"\"(*{}|:\"<>?\"\""; 
qualdata = qualdata.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");
System.out.println(qualdata);
```

Comment: Hi Beiamin, I tried using escape characters .. Still no luck   String qualdata = "\"!@#$^%^&*()\"\"(*{}|:\"<>?\""; 
 
 qualdata = qualdata.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");

Comment: I edited the code.Is this in line with your requirements.

Comment: I did this  : tempQualData= qualdata.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");  but value is appending to excel as  \!@#$^%^&*()(*{}|:\"<>?\""

Comment: this is my input String   ""!@#$^%^&*()(*{}|:"<>?""  , I tried using StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(qualdata). even it is giving as   "!@#$^%^&*()(*{}|:""<>?""""